# How can I force nginx to start a new access.log file?

Tags: nginx, logrotate

I have to grep through nginx access logs to nullroute troublesome IP addresses regularly, in my estimate about every 15 minutes, and I may have to do whole blocks instead of just the individual IPs.

When the IP addresses have already been blackholed the `ip route` command responds with `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`, so I need to get nginx to start creating new logs to avoid duplicates.

Is there some way to that? Restarting nginx seems to have no effect.

Comment: You will need to move or delete the old logfile before you restart Nginx. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/logrotation/).

Comment: this could be done by setting logrotate configuration to 1) switch fileunconditionnaly 2) restart nginx as part of process and 3) manualy run `logrotate`. see `man 5 logorotate.conf` and `man logrotate`